# Additions to One to Many Relationships Have to be done on Master Side in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities involved in a one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Voter
{
    // VoterID and CountyID define a unique primary key
    public int VoterID {get;set;}
    public int CountyID {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Contact
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
    // VoterID and CountyID define a unique foreign key
    public int VoterID {get;set;}
    public int CountyID {get;set;}
    public Voter Voter {get;set;}
}
```

The composite primary key and foreign key relationship are defined in Context.OnModelCreating() as follows:

```
builder.Entity<Voter>().HasKey( x => new { x.CountyID, x.VoterID } );

// one to many relationship: voter -> contact
builder.Entity<Voter>()
    .HasMany( v => v.Contacts )
    .WithOne( c => c.Voter )
    .HasForeignKey( c => new { c.CountyID, c.VoterID } );

builder.Entity<Contact>()
    .HasOne( c => c.Voter )
    .WithMany( v => v.Contacts )
    .HasForeignKey( c => new { c.CountyID, c.VoterID } );
```

If I try to add a new Contact directly to the Contacts table, either like this:

```
_context.Contacts.Add(new Contact() {
    VoterID = ...,
    CountyID = ...,
    Data = ....,
});
```

or like this:

```
Voter voter = _context.Voters.Single(...);

_context.Contacts.Add(new Contact() {
    Voter = voter,
    Data = ....,
});
```

the record doesn't get added. No error, no exception, just a silent fail.

However, adding the new Contact from the Voter instance works:

```
Voter voter = _context.Voters.Include(v=>v.Contacts).Single(...);
voter.Contacts = voter.Contacts ?? new List<Contact>();
voter.Contacts.Add( new Contact() {
    Voter = voter,
    Data = ....,
});
```

I don't understand why adding the new entity from the "one" side works but adding it from the "many" side doesn't.

**Edit**

In reviewing this post I realized, in simplifying the model, I may have inadvertently left out an important fact: the primary key, and hence the foreign key in Contact, is composite. I've updated the question to include these elements.

Comment: Can't reproduce - either code works as expected. EF Core 1.0.1, Full NET4.6.1 if that matters.

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues with the all the files necessary to reproduce this.